# C++ convert enum pointer to another enum class pointer

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

Let's say I have the following code

```cpp
template <class T>
struct ArrayRef { ArrayRef(const T *, size_t count); };

enum class EImpl { In, Out };
enum ECApi { IN, OUT };

static_assert(ECApi::IN == static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<EImpl>>(EImpl::In));
static_assert(ECApi::OUT == static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<EImpl>>(EImpl::Out));

void impl(ArrayRef<EImpl> es);
void c_api(const ECApi *e, size_t count) { impl(ArrayRef{???, count}); }
```

where `EImpl` and `impl` are existing internal items, `ECApi` and `c_api` are new items I added for the public C API.

I prefer not to modify the parameters of `impl` function. Is there a way to convert `const ECApi *` to `const EImpl *e` without extra allocation and UB (e.g. violating strict aliasing rule)?

Link to [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/r3sadch8E).

Comment: Don't try to outsmart yourself, just write some explicit conversion functions and use them where needed. And why would you need pointers to an enum value anyway? Just pass them by value or as std::vector<enum_type>

Comment: What is the underlying and actual problem you have? Why would a solution like this solve that problem? Perhaps there are other and better solutions to that original problem? Right now your question is too much of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) for us to be able to properly help you solve the original problem.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Using pointer because it's a C API, obviously there is no way to easily use `std::vector`. Does adding some explicit conversion functions mean I have to change the parameter list of `impl` function?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think I've described my X problem - I'm adding a public C API for a C++ function.

Comment: Why do you duplicate `IN` and `OUT` as `In` and `Out`? The easier thing would be to not do that

Comment: Make a (thin) wrapper for you C api in C++ and do all the conversion there. Then you can give the C++ api the types you want. (and never look at the "C" types under the hood again).

Comment: Scoped enumeration values can be converted to the underlying type. Since your underlying type is `int`, you can use `static_cast` to convert the values to `int`. Like for example `static_cast<int>(EImpl::In)`

Comment: And to ensure that the C enumeration have the exact same values, I would rather do something like `enum ECApi { IN = static_cast<int>(EImpl::In), ... };`.

Comment: I interpret the question as wanting to micro-optimize to avoid a single value copy of a enum? There is at least one problem, even if you attempt to use a union approach for borderline-legal type punning: the C style enum does not have the same size/underlying storage guarantees as the C++ enum class type enum: the former need only promise to fit its enumerators in a 2s complement bitstyle storage, whereas the latter respects its underlying type, which, in lack of explicitly specifying it, is `int`.

Comment: Note "Two enumeration types are layout-compatible enumerations if they have the same underlying type."  This allows you to directly `memcpy` between them.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'll add to your comment that OP's `EImpl` and `ECApi` are not layout-compatible, as per [\[dcl.enum\]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.enum#8).

Comment: @dfrib: It's the paragraph before (/7) that matters, since it relates to underlying type.  [Underlying type is the only factor that determines layout compatibility](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/enum#dcl.enum-9)  Since the underlying type is not fixed for either enum, it is implementation-dependent what that underlying type of each will be, and whether they will be the same.